# How to download content from a webpage every few seconds with python?

Tags: python, web-crawler

I have a URL say `www.someurl.com/blah.xml`.

I want to write a python script that goes to that URL, gets its contents, and saves it to a file on the local hard disk. Not sure what the best way of going about this or if any recommended libraries are necessary for this kind of thing.

Comment: Have you looked at urllib/urllib2 yet?

Comment: See http://docs.python.org/howto/urllib2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
import urllib2 as urllib

page = urllib.urlopen('http://www.someurl.com/blah.xml')
with open('output.xml', 'w') as f:
  f.write(page.read())
```

Then you could maybe make a cron job to run every five minutes. At the terminal, type `crontab -e` and make a line that says:

```
*/5 * * * * python path/to/script.py
```

I'm not an expert with crontabs, so someone correct that if I'm wrong.